# How to get the unparsed entity attribute's value from XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, dtd, saxon, xalan

I have a problem with XSLT and unparsed entity in XML. Here is a fictional scenario. First I got an XML file named doc.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<!DOCTYPE document [
<!ELEMENT document (employee)*>
<!ELEMENT employee (lastname, firstname)>
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!NOTATION FOO SYSTEM 'text/xml'>
<!ENTITY ATTACHMENT SYSTEM 'attach.xml' NDATA FOO>
<!ATTLIST employee
       detail ENTITY #IMPLIED>
]>
<document>
    <employee detail="ATTACHMENT">
        <lastname>Bob</lastname>
        <firstname>Kevin</firstname>
    </employee>
</document>
```

In this XML file, I use an unparsed entity(NDATA) for the attribute "detail" of the element "employee".  The attach.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<name>Bob Kevin</name>
```

Then i want to use XSLT to generate an output together with the attach.xml embedded. My XSLT file is named doc.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="document">
<Document>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="employee"/>
</Document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="employee">
Employee is:  <xsl:value-of select="@detail"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Finally, I run using Xalan 2.7.1 :

```
java -jar xalan.jar -IN doc.xml -XSL doc.xsl -OUT docout.xml
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
Employee is:  ATTACHMENT
</Document>
```

This is not what i want. I want the output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
Employee is:  <name>Bob Kevin</name>
</Document>
```

How should I rewrite the XSLT script to get the correct result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The solution in XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="document">
<Document>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="employee"/>
</Document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="employee">
Employee is:  <xsl:value-of select=
"unparsed-text(unparsed-entity-uri(@detail))"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note** the following:

1. **The use of the XSLT functions [`unparsed-text()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-unparsed-text) and [`unparsed-entity-uri()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20#function-unparsed-entity-uri).**
2. **The text of the attach.xml file will be escaped in the output**. If you want to see it unescaped, use the **[`"cdata-section-elements"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output)** attribute of the **[`<xsl:output/>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output)** instruction.

Comment: I got a warning in Saxon-B 9.1.0.5, change  stylesheet to version="2.0" works. Thanks again!

Comment: @jscoot: Thanks, I corrected this accidental mistake from my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately when using [Saxon API for .Net](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnet/dotnetapi.html) these functions will not work, _Unparsed entities are not notified to Saxon by the Microsoft parser. The XSLT functions unparsed-entity-uri() and unparsed-entity-public-id() will therefore not work_, see [XML Parsing in .NET](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnet/xmlparsing.html)

Comment: @DaveAnderson, Yes, it's a pity. One can still use, beside Saxon (J), also MSXML3 or MSXML6 and these XSLT processors produce the wanted result whith the XSLT 1.0 transformation from the answer by @ jscoot below

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, Dimitre Novatchev.  According to your answer, i got my result in XSLT 1.0. For those who may be interested, please refer to http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1243 for a discussion. Here is my solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="document">
<Document>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="employee"/>
</Document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="employee">
Employee is: <xsl:copy-of select="document(unparsed-entity-uri(@detail))"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the the following line from above:

```
 <xsl:copy-of select="document(unparsed-entity-uri(@detail))"/>
```

Comment: @jscoot: That's nice!. However it is only possible, because your ENTITY is associated with an xml document. In the general case (non-XML document), the only way to read the data is by using the XSLT 2.0 function unparsed-text(). Glad I could be of help.